# How to set default/fallback value in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set **default/fallback value** in order to see something in **layout preview**, when attributes are set by **style**?

Comment: Are you looking for [Design-time view attributes](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#design-time_view_attributes)?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK that's what I was looking for. Can you create "official answer"? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Design-time view attributes](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#design-time_view_attributes).

From the documentation:

> You can insert sample data in your layout preview by using the tools:
>   prefix instead of android: with any  attribute from the Android
>   framework. This is useful when the attribute's value isn't populated
>   until runtime but you want to see the effect beforehand, in the layout
>   preview.
>
> For example, if the android:text attribute value is set at runtime or
>   you want to see the layout with a value different than the default,
>   you can add tools:text to specify some text for the layout preview
>   only.

[image]